# Popup datepicker when user presses a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

im a beginner in ios, pls help me how to show a popup calendar when user press a button. I already have my button below

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame= CGRectMake(60, 560, 150, 30);
[button setTitle:@"Select Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: You can give this a whirl.  https://github.com/square/objc-TimesSquare

Comment: for iphone or ipad ??

Comment: Just have a look at to my answer

Comment: .one more question if i may.,, what property do i need to set if i want this pop up to be modal,, so behind buttons wont be clickable??...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In .h file**

```
 UIDatePicker *datepicker;
 UIPopoverController *popOverForDatePicker;
```

**Please set the Delegate in .h file** `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`

**In .m File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame= CGRectMake(60, 560, 150, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"Select Date" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIView *viewForDatePicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];

    datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.hidden = NO;
    datepicker.date = [NSDate date];
    [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(LabelChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [viewForDatePicker addSubview:datepicker];
    [viewController.view addSubview:viewForDatePicker];

    popOverForDatePicker = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    popOverForDatePicker.delegate = self;
    [popOverForDatePicker setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 100) animated:NO];
    [popOverForDatePicker presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown| UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight) animated:YES];
}
-(void)LabelChange:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datepicker.date]]);
}
```

Comment: Just paste this and let me know

Comment: it works men...one more question if i may.,, what property do i need to set if i want this pop up to be modal,, so behind buttons wont be clickable??..@Manohar

Comment: Couldn't get you.. Come again... Modal means ??

Comment: so that the buttons in the behind uiview wont be clickable when the datepicker pops up...

Comment: if (popOverForDatePicker.popoverVisible)
    {
        NSLog(@"Visible");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Visible");
    }

Comment: Instead of NSLog just disable your buttons and enable your buttons in the condition

Comment: Hello. got the solution dear ?? @user2234264

Comment: yeah,, i used presentViewController...

Comment: UIPopoverController is made only for iPad. This code works for iPad but throws exception for iPhone

Comment: This is only valid for iPads

Comment: popOverForDatePicker presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame 

not found on object of type